# getting the whole json data instead of paricular string

Tags: android, json

I'm unable to get data in specific string description in my JSON. Instead of that I'm getting whole JSON data in my webview when clicked on listitem.

## JSON file

```
{
"status": "ok",
"source": "techcrunch",
"sortBy": "top",
-"articles": [
-{
"author": "Devin Coldewey",
"title": "A mesh network spontaneously erupts in the US and helps connect Puerto Rico",
"description": "When goTenna put out their Mesh device earlier this year, I thought the off-grid gadgets would be great for an emergency kit or back-country hike. But it..",
"url": "https://techcrunch.com/2017/11/14/a-mesh-network-spontaneously-erupts-in-the-us-and-helps-connect-puerto-rico/",
"urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/11/gotennapr.png",
"publishedAt": "2017-11-14T18:41:28Z"
},
```

## Current code:

```
package com.example.murarilal.volley;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class ArticleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_article);
        String url="https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=59b308aec9f242fe98b527ab9ba93199";


        WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(url,null,intent.getStringExtra("description"),"text/html","UTF-8");
        webView.loadUrl(url);



    }

}
```

**this is the main activity**
    package com.example.murarilal.volley;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RequestQueue queue;
    ListView listView;
    List<Hero> heroList;



    private String url="https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=59b308aec9f242fe98b527ab9ba93199";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        home();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        heroList = new ArrayList<>();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ArticleActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("description",url);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });



    }

    public void home()
    {

        JsonObjectRequest request =new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));

                    JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("articles");

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        Hero hero=new Hero( (String) array.getJSONObject(i).get("title"),(String) array.getJSONObject(i).get("urlToImage"));
                        heroList.add(hero);

                    }

                    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(heroList, getApplicationContext());
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }

        }
                , new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });



        queue.add(request);
    }


    }
```

Comment: Could you prettify your JSON? Would be easier to read and you would see that it's not a complete JSON... the end is missing

Comment: Can you describe for me what you want? and what happens?

Comment: I only need your `Hero` class code to give you a full answer! Edit your question add the code in `Hero` class!

Comment: Edit your question and add code from `Hero` class!

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Hero hero = heroList.get(i);
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ArticleActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("description",hero.getDescription());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Comment: How did you know `getDescription()` exists?

Comment: Oh, I'm assuming by the name of the param.

Comment: haha, well, the idea is that he should pass a value from the objet and not the link I guess.

Comment: I know that is  his/her only problem but he has not given any more descriptions on that!